# How to delete block of code inside curly brackets?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a file that has some code block:

```
dimensions{
   dim1{
      //foo
   }
   dim2{
      //bar
   }
}
```

How can I delete the whole 'dimensions' block including everything inside? Taking into consideration that I don't know how many blocks there is inside, but I'm sure that there us same number of opening and closing curly brackets?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can't. Regular expressions are a type 3 grammar in the Chomsky hierarchy. These grammars cannot keep track of the context/how many brackets are open. I say “maybe” because I'm not sure whether there are or aren't some extensions in sed compared to “real regular expressions”.

Comment: @MatthiasWimmer well good to know, I'm stuck on this for half a day already

Comment: @MatthiasWimmer and if I would know the exact number of sub blocks? Would it be possible then?

Comment: @EvgeniyMishustin Yes. In case you know the exact number of sub blocks or at least the maximum number of sub blocks, you should be able to express it. Also if you know that there is only one block at the outermost level, it can be expressed.

Comment: @MatthiasWimmer I know the exact blocks quantity. So this means I know the exact closing brackets number. For example I need to delete 4 closing brackets and stop. How can I regex it ?

Comment: @sindri_baldur that's the requirement

Comment: @MatthiasWimmer You can do that in perl, but not in any sed implementation I've ever seen.

Comment: This looks like json and so just use jq.

Comment: @RamanSailopal How does that data look like json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using vim it's fairly simple to match any line that contains `dimensions` using `:global`:

```
:[range]g[lobal]/{pattern}/[cmd]
```

eg:

```
:g/dimensions/print
```

Where the command `print` will print all matched lines:

Changing the command to `normal!` one can execute normal mode commands on the matched lines, eg `d`elete, or `y`ank.

```
:g/dimensions/normal! ...
```

The command `d` deletes, but needs a motion following it, eg: `$` to delete until the newline character, or in our case we can use `%` which finds the matching pair of character, `{` matches with `}`, `(` matches with `)` etc.

```
:g/dimensions/normal! d%
```

One can invoke vim from the command line and request it to execute commands with `-c`:

```
vim -c 'g/dimensions/normal! d%' [inputfile]...
```

Remember to save and close to avoid vim from staying open:

```
-c 'wq'
```

As vim can be configured to ones needs via the vimrc file and from the environment one can disable this with:

```
-u NONE
```

All together:

```
vim -u NONE -c 'g/dimensions/normal! d%' -c 'wq' [inputfile]...
```

Comment: Oh, nice! I didn't know that `%` could work at the beginning of the line!

Comment: Much better answer than mine:)

Answer (score 2):

If you can use vim instead of sed, you can take profit of the non-interactive mode:

```
vim input.txt -u NONE -c "call search('\\<dimensions{', 'w')" -c "norm maf{%d'a" -c "wq"
```

Be aware that this version will edit the file in place.

This method is nice because it will take into account the recursive nesting of the curly bracket blocks.

However this has some issues:

- If you have many files to process, I guess this will be really slower than using sed;
- The `norm` command is not easy to understand if you don't know vim

Comment: Why the need to store the position with `ma`?

Comment: You might also be able to use `search(...., 'we')` to avoid the need for `f{`.

Comment: @andlr about `ma`: `d%` is not block delete, so it will not delete `dimensions`

Comment: @andlrc: about `'we'`, you're right, `vim -u NONE input.txt -c "call search('\\<dimensions{', 'we')" -c "norm ma%d'a" -c "wq"` is ok as well

Comment: Other improvements are welcome:) I saw that nvim has a nice `-es` cli option which would be more adapted, but I didn't mention it because it is not portable between vim and nvim

Answer (score 1):

Using `perl` and a recursive regular expression:

```
$ cat input.txt
some text before.
dimensions{
   dim1{
      //foo
   }
   dim2{
      //bar
   }
}
some text after.
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/dimensions(\{(?:(?>[^{}]+)|(?1))*\})\n//' input.txt
some text before.
some text after.
```